# assign multiple zeros to variable

Tags: vba, variables

Ii need to assign my variable called `digitscounter` with zeroes. For an example, if I key in `399`, then I want to assign `digitscounter` as `000`. If I key in `4568`, then `0000`. I just want to know how to assign `digitscounter` variable so that it can hold on zeroes.

How do i declare the `digitscounter` variable? Later on, I need to use the digitscounter in command `format(i, "digitscounter")`. I have already tried the following:

```
Dim digitscounter As String
digitscounter = "000"        'for 3 digits ofcourse
```

Unfortunately, the error run time error 91 came out. I need your expertise guys. Sorry, I am quite new to VBA, so bear with me yeah?.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing it correctly. If you key in `4568` into a variable (say `i`), then you can do this:

```
Dim digitscounter As String
digitscounter = String(Len(i), "0")

Debug.Print Format$(i, digitscounter)    ' => "4568"
```

Of course, if `i` is a numeric data type, it will drop any leading zeros so your `digitscounter` string won't account for them. You'd need to read the number into a `String` instead.